# Scheme : Lambda inside quoted list is unbound

Tags: lisp, interpreters, scheme

I'm programming a small lisp/scheme interpreter and I came across the following situation :

When a quoted list contains lambdas, they are not parsed as lambdas.
Here is a sample code ([live on repl.it](https://repl.it/Bhxk/1)):

```
(define list1 '(
                   (lambda (x) (+ x 1))
                   (lambda (y) (+ y 2))
                )
)

(define add1 (car list1))
(print (add1 1))
```

and the result is  :

```
Error: ('lambda ('x) ('+ 'x 1)) is not a function [add1]
```

Is it normal behaviour ? I thought lambdas were special forms that should always be binded.

If it is indeed the expected behaviour : When my Parser parse the Lambda and wraps it in an object (say, of type LambdaWrap) and my Interpreter returns that object unevaluated then I guess that this is a wrong behaviour because it's supposed to return some unbinded symbols instead. Is that right ?

Comment: Your form **is** bound. It's just not a function. It's a list that *looks* like a function definition. You may want to look up partial quoting.

Comment: I think you will get much better feedback on [Stack Overlow](http://stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is: what do you mean by "parsed as a lambda"? 
Suppose I write this in Java:

```
String fun = "() -> 3"; 
int y = fun();
```

It fails, because you don't expect the string to be parsed, evaluated as a lambda expression and be directly usable as a function, do you?

The same applies with strings in Lisp and in a similar way with `quote`: the quoted form is read but not evaluated. More precisely, the evaluation of `(quote x)` returns `x` (the expression itself), and not `(eval x)`, the value this expression yields upon evaluation.

So instead of having a function object, what you obtain after doing `(car list1)` is a list of values, the first one being the `lambda` symbol.

If you want to build a list of functions, use `(list ...)`, which evaluates its arguments.

---

You say:

> Ok but why is the inner list evaluated ? i.e : I get `('lambda ('x) ('+ 'x 1))` instead of : `('lambda '( 'x ') '( '+ 'x 1') )`

The reader takes strings and produces a value, which is a symbolic expression: for example, an object in memory with `car` and `cdr` fields.

Your question assumes that this is a list of *tokens*, like quoted parenthesis etc., which is not the case. At this point you manipulate *abstract* syntax trees.

In order to see this value, your system must *print* it, and it tries to do it so that the printed form can be read back. If you play with `repl.it` a little, you can see how a regular list is printed, etc.

The particular message you see is taken from an error message where honestly, the form is printed in a strange way, different from the normal output as seen from the REPL. Maybe someone else can explain why this error message is formatted the way it is.

Comment: Ok but why is the inner list evaluated ?
i.e : I get ('lambda ('x) ('+ 'x 1)) instead of : ('lambda '( 'x ') '( '+ 'x 1') )

Comment: @Julien__ The inner list is not evaluated. I edited the answer to cover this more in details. Hope it helps.